# how to use aria-labelledby for *ngFor accessiblity in Angular2 for screen reader announcement

Tags: angular

Angular2 accessibility Issue: 
   screen reader Nvda tool announcements are as below.
    Employee Name Peter request check box  not checked
    Employee Name Peter request check box  not checked

it should announce Tom for second value, Expected Result: 
  Employee Name Tom request check box not checked. 
  How to fix this ?

```
employees array in component.ts file as below.
employees= [
    { "id":1, "name": "Peter", "age":32},
    { "id":2, "name": "Tom", "age":28}
  ];

component.html file as below:
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label id="empName">Employee Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label id="request">request</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let emp of employees; let i = index;" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <span id="name">{{emp.name}}</span>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="empName name request" />
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the solution on my own. By using index, generating unique id's and then passing that id in aria-labelledby. 
something like this.

{{emp.name}}
[attr.aria-labelledby]="'name-' + i"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is this the span line

```
<span id="name">{{emp.name}}</span>
```

Remember that id belongs to only one element so when you assign the first span the id of name it can only refer to the first one which is peter. If you use that id again, it will still refer to peter.

To fix this I changed the span to bind the id to the emp.name string. Now there will be an id = Peter for the first span, and an id = Tom on the second span.

```
<span id="{{emp.name}}">{{emp.name}}</span>
```

next you must adjust your checkbox input to bind the aria attribute to the string expression. make sure to leave a space between the single quote so that the string expression will have spaces once the concatenation is complete

```
<input type="checkbox" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'empName ' + emp.name + ' request'"/>
```

This will give you the accessibility effect you are looking for. Tested it with Nvda tool.

P.S:

In the case that these changes affect your CSS for id = name I would recommend keeping name as a class instead. that way each span can still have access to the same css.

Comment: Why [attr.aria-labelledby] works while applying the attribute itself is removed from the DOM after it compiles?

Comment: Using the employee name as id isn't a great idea, there can be duplicates too, and it can have spaces. Using an index is more fool-proof.